# How do i pass data from view to controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I just started working with MVC with a simple web store application. I separated a data column type of NVARCHAR with `.Split` method. I have placed those separated data inside selectable jquery element

as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectable").selectable({
            stop: function () {
                var result = $("#select-result").empty();
                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                    var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                    result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
                });
            }
        });
    });
<p>
                                    <b>Available Sizes</b>
                                    @{
                                        var Availablesize = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',');

                                    }
                                    @foreach (var item in Availablesize)
                                    {
                                        <ol id="selectable">
                                            <li class="ui-widget-content"><span>@item//</span></li>
                                        </ol>
                                    }
                                </p>
```

Now i want implement a feature that when a user selects one of those separated items and press a button Add To Cart the value of that

element should be passed to the following controller:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
```

Any idea? please help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart")',
       type: 'POST',
       data: allData  ,
       success: function(result) {
        // process the results from the controller
      }
   });
```

> where allData  = { Cart :  Cartdetails,    productId : 1,   returnUrl : returnUrl};